# Conjectures inspired in the context of Casas-Alvero conjecture, via the logarithmic derivative of derivatives of a polynomial

Tags: abstract-algebra, derivatives, polynomials, reference-request, conjectures

In the post we assume that $P(x)=a_0+a_{1}x+\ldots+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+a_{n}x^n$ is a polynomial of degree $1<\deg(P)=d=n$ defined over a field $K$ of characteristic zero. We denote its derivatives as $P^{(i)}(x)$ (writting $P^{(0)}(x)=P(x)$), and $a_n$ denotes the leading coefficient of $P(x)$.

I've stated two conjectures (as speculations from the fact) inspired in that I've proven inductively that each polynomial $p(x)$ of degree $1<\deg(p)$ (and with corresponding $a_n\neq 0$) satisfies $$p(x)=a_n\cdot\left(\frac{n-l}{\frac{d}{dx}\log p^{(l)}(x)} \right)^n\tag{1}$$
for each integer $l$ with $0\leq l<n-1$.

**Conjecture 1.** *Let* $P(x)$ *a polynomial of degree* $1<n$, *thus we assume* $P^{(n)}(0)\neq 0$. *If the equation* $$P(x)=\frac{P^{(n)}(0)}{n!}\cdot\left(\frac{n-l}{\frac{d}{dx}\log P^{(l)}(x)} \right)^n$$ *holds for each integer* $0\leq l<n-1$, *then* $P(x)$ *has the form* $$P(x)=\frac{P^{(n)}(0)}{n!}\cdot(x-\alpha)^n$$ *for some element* $\alpha\in K$.

I know the statement of the called Casas-Alvero conjecture from Wikipedia [*Casas-Alvero conjecture*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Casas-Alvero_conjecture). I've speculated (while I don't know if this has a good mathematical content, or if these ideas are in the literature in some way more or less explicit) if from previous simple idea one can to state an equivalent form of Casas-Alvero conjecture.

**Conjecture 2.** *Let* $P(x)$ *a polynomial of degree* $1<n$ *and leading coefficient* $a_n\neq 0$. *The Casas-Alvero conjecture is equivalent to that the equation* $$P(x)\cdot\left(P^{(l+1)}(x)\right)^n=a_n\left((n-1)P^{(l)}(x)\right)^n,\tag{2}$$
*holds for each integer* $0\leq l<n-1$.

> **Question.** Can you prove or refute (providing a counterexample, or reasoning if my conjectures have not a good mathematical content) these conjectures Conjcture 1 and Conjecture 2? **Many thanks.**

I don't know if these conjectures Conjecture 1 and Conjecture 2 are in the literature, my idea was very simple: that is to study the logarithmic derivative of derivatives of a given polynomial of the cited form, if it is in the literature please refer it in a comment or in your answer and I try to search and study this from the corresponding articles.

Comment: Feel free to add your critics, if my conjecture aren't interesting I can to delete the post. Many thanks.

Comment: Feel free to add comments about if it possible to get counterexamples or prove Conjecture 1. And what about Conjecture 2? (I would like to know if my idea concerning Conjecture 2 really could be related to Casas-Alvero conjecture)